# BL654 USB and Atmel chip on dev board

Tags: atmel, nordic

I don't understand the USB port on the BL654 Ble module. Is this something that is only required / functioning when one writes a program with the Nordic SDK? Or does it work using SmartBASIC as well? The SmartBASIC documentation reveals zero info about it.

I also don't understand the presence of the Atmel chip on the BL654 dev board. Why do we need it, or what does it do there?

Edit: The dev board has many parts managing a wide range of power options and manual switches to select from these. I really don't think that the Atmel controller has anything to do with power management. The module itself has UART and SWD/JTAG, and the board has an FTDI chip to manage communication over USB.

I would really like to hear from someone who had read the documentation and has experience with the module / dev board. I would like to know if programming with the SDK kills the AT command / smartBASIC capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Atmel chip is an SWD programmer / debugger and the USB interface necessary for that.

The USB of the module can not be programmed using smartBASIC. Using the Nordic SDK it can be used to make the module act like various USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

So, to get the nomenclature as I think you're using it:

This is what you call a module:
[image: BL654]

And this is the dev board:
[image: Dev kit]

Source for both the Laird website that also has links to documentation, [here](https://www.lairdconnect.com/wireless-modules/bluetooth-modules/bluetooth-5-modules/bl654-series-bluetooth-module-nfc).

> I don't understand the USB port on the BL654 Ble module. Is this something that is only required / functioning when one writes a program with the Nordic SDK?

No. It's a USB port. You can write firmware for the nRF52840 (which is the core component of these modules) which can talk USB!

> Or does it work using SmartBASIC as well? The SmartBASIC documentation reveals zero info about it.

Never heard of smartBASIC; I don't know whether that environment supports the USB peripheral and has appropriate drivers. Feels like something you'd do when you grow out of the need to write software in BASIC, just as a feeling, because suddenly, knowing how to deal with an interrupt and a raw buffer becomes a necessity, and not something you can hide behind a simplistic language runtime. It seems that, while it can be pre-parsed, it's always an interpreted language. So, I guess this is a language for non-timing-critical things, and not something you can really use to implement your own USB device stack.

> I also don't understand the presence of the Atmel chip on the BL654 dev board. Why do we need it, or what does it do there?

Without reading the documentation: It's a dev board. It needs to manage power, it needs to offer a host computer the ability to talk to the device being worked on, etc. Most dev kits have a microcontroller next to the target!

Comment: If the USB port is as simple as you put it "you can write firmware... which can talk USB", then I could do it using any GPIO pin. But the module has dedicated D+, D-, VBUS pins. These are not alternative functions, these are the only things these pins do. I suspect some function hiding there.

Comment: no, you can't do it using any GPIO pin. You need to write firmware that controls the integrated USB peripheral. There's nothing hiding there, but an integrated USB peripheral!

Comment: The dev board has other stuff on it to manage power. To talk to the module UART is exposed and there's an FTDI  chip on in. My question really is: does it have a function in the context of the dev board (JTAG programmer for example so we don't have to have one), or it's just there to play with (like the push buttons) without any particular function?

Comment: "Most dev kits have a microcontroller next to the target!" Ok. But why does THIS dev kit have an Atmel controller on board? What can I do with it? In what situation is this any good for me? Example please.

Comment: I already addressed that: "It needs to manage power, it needs to offer a host computer the ability to talk to the device being worked on"

Comment: Yes, you have said that already but it's not helpful at all. Manage power?! No. "ability to talk": the module itself has UART and SWD/JTAG. For the USB to UART there's an FTDI on the dev board. There are no other communication options.

Comment: Seriously, if you're not satisfied with simply believing that your PC has no means by itself to talk to a debug interface or bring up multiple voltage chains on a board, I'm not sure what to do. You're working with microcontrollers, the fact that you can debug software on them, and that you can't hang one into plain air and see it start doing something useful should be all kinds of obvious to you! Since it took me 10 s with Google to find the user guide to the eval board, I'm also fairly certain you can read the section on that it connects to the swd interface yourself.